# Error 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

I wrote a script to do interpolation

```
import scipy.interpolate
import csv
inputfile1 = 'test.csv'
outputfile = 'Day1_out.csv'
distance_list = []
EC_list = []
new_dist_list=[]
outfile = open(outputfile,'w')
outfile.write('Distance,EC\n')

with open (inputfile1,'rb') as csvfile:
    f1 = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    next(f1) #skip header line
    for row in f1:
        dist = row[12]
        EC=row[13]
        distance_list.append(dist)
        EC_list.append(EC)
y_interp = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(distance_list,EC_list)
new_dist = 561.7
end = 560.2
while new_dist>end:
    new_dist_list.append(dist)
    new_dist=new_dist-0.2
for distance in new_dist_list:
    EC=y_interp(distance)
    outfile.write(str(distance)+','+str(EC)+'\n')
outfile.close()
```

When I ran the script it gave me the error message
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "D:\14046\Scripts\interpolation_RoR.py", line 41, in <module>
    EC=y_interp(distance)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\polyint.py", line 54, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 448, in _evaluate
    out_of_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py", line 474, in _check_bounds
    if self.bounds_error and below_bounds.any():

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'
```

Anyone has any idea where I have errors?

BTW, the input file have these values for distance and EC

Distance,EC

561.8,450

561.78,446

561.7,444

561.2,440

561.02,438

560.5,437

560.1,435

Thanks,

Comment: Execute this with the Python Shell IDLE, in the debug menu open the stack viewer and have a look at `self.bounds_error` and post it. There is already an error and scipy seems not to handle this in a correct way.

Comment: Is there a way that I can attach photo with question? I want to print screen the stack viewer and attach here. I seems lost in all these info. It does say "if self.bounds_error and below_bounds.any()" then after that it listed many items/function

Comment: There is a way. Edit and there is an image symbol.

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation to be able to post image :( Under self.bounds_error and below_bounds.any()\locals, I have below_bound = True, self = <scipy.interpolate.interp1d object at 0x03670F50>, above_bounds = False and x_new = array([561.7]). I guess the error is at above_bounds but could not find any obvious error message inside it

Comment: I found that I had a mistake. I forgot to convert items in dist_list and EC_list to float before interpolation. I fixed it but it still gave me error ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range

Answer (score 1):

We are getting the same error message here. I think this does not necessarily need to be a problem with your code.

In our case switching to `SciPy version 0.15.0` instead of `0.13.x` solves the problem.

So it looks like the current version of SciPy accepts a wider range of input values.